# Why did my query get 100x worse when changing 'where' to 'join'

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I modified a query so that it uses a join instead of a `where` + `select` statements so that I can give it multiple input events instead of one, but the performance got much worse. I ran the old and the new query on the same input event (one event) and it runs in 5000ms instead of 30ms.

I am using PostgresSQL version 13.

The input event in this case is `Table_C`. This used to always be one row, but now it could be up to 50 rows.

**Old query:**

```
select * from Table_A a
where ST_Intersects(a.center,(select center from Table_B b, Table_C c where b.id = c.id))
```

**New query:**

```
with b_c as materialized (
  select center
  from Table_B b
  join Table_C c on b.id = c.id
)

select *
from Table_A a 
join b_c on ST_Intersects(a.center, b_c.center)
```

Generating the b_c table takes 30ms, and the second part about 4000ms. If I change the `join` line with:

```
where ST_Intersects(a.center, (select center from b_c limit 1))
```

Then the whole query takes 30ms instead of 4000ms.

Any ideas why this may happen? I noticed in the *explain* that now it does an "Append" at the highest level instead of the "Gather" that it used to do.

Comment: Without getting into details, your original query clearly says you are interested in rows from table_a a, only. İt can just scan that table once. The other would require returning rows multiple times if there multiple matches, so the results can be different, so it has to perform the joins , it can no longer just scan the first table

Comment: Please show the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both queries.

Comment: @tinazmu That makes sense, but do you know why would the performance get so much worse the 'input' event which is Table_C is only one row in both cases? So, even though it's a join, I would think it would only have to scan Table_A once.

Comment: @jjanes I'll try to get that and see how it would fit on StackOverflow

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons:

- The new query retrieves all columns from `Table_A`, `Table_B`, and `Table_C`, while the original query only retrieved columns from `Table_A`. This means PostgreSQL will need to retrieve all columns from Table_B and Table_C instead of just `Table_B.center`, `Table_B.id`, and `Table_C.id`. If you don't actually need any columns from `Table_B` or `Table_C`, you might get a performance improvement by changing `select *` to `select a.*`.
- The new query potentially fetches a much larger number of rows, depending on how many rows in `Table_B` and `Table_C` match the conditions.
- The table statistics might be outdated. See [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) and [AUTOVACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) for details on how PostgreSQL gathers statistics.

Another possibility is that the PostgreSQL query optimizer orders the joins poorly, and calls `ST_Intersects` for every combination of `a` and `b` before filtering down to the rows where `b.id = c.id`. You could experiment with introducing a CTE like this:

```
with b_c as (
  select *
  from Table_B b
  join Table_C c on b.id = c.id
)
select *
from Table_A a 
join b_c on ST_Intersects(a.center, b_c.center)
```

and see if that performs better. You could also try explicitly materialising the CTE by using `with b_c as materialized ( ... )`, as described in [Common Table Expression Materialization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7).

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
1- In the actual code, there was no change in the number of columns returned between the two queries, but I was trying to simplify it for the post.

2- It shouldn't be a big difference since Table_C became 1-10 rows instead of 1 and same with Table_B. Also, when testing performance between the two, I only used one event for both queries, so the number of returned rows is the same. 

3- I never heard of this one before. I'll take a look!

Comment: I updated my answer with another possible explanation, different join order, and a suggestion on how to experiment to see if it is the cause.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that as well, it did not show a significant improvement